# Implementation of BST C++ Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

I have implemented binary search tree in C++ and for some reason I am not seeing where the segmentation fault occurs. But I do notice that when I comment out root = node in the first conditional statement in addNode the error goes away. What exactly is a segmentation fault and how does it related to pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class bstNode
{
public:
    int value;
    bstNode *left;
    bstNode *right;

    bstNode(){};
    ~bstNode(){};

    bstNode(int value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
    }

    bstNode(int value, bstNode *left, bstNode *right)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;
    }

    bstNode *root;

    void addNode(int value)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            bstNode *node = new bstNode(value);
            root = node;
        }
        else
        {
            bstNode *focusNode = root;
            bstNode *parent;

            while (focusNode != NULL)
            {
                if (value > focusNode->value)
                {
                    focusNode = focusNode->right;
                    if (focusNode == NULL)
                    {
                        focusNode->right = new bstNode(value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    focusNode = focusNode->left;
                    if (focusNode == NULL)
                    {
                        focusNode->left = new bstNode(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void printBST(bstNode *node)
    {
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            printBST(node->left);
            cout << node->value;
            printBST(node->right);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    bstNode *node = new bstNode();
    node->addNode(7);
    node->addNode(2);
    node->addNode(18);
    node->addNode(6);
    node->addNode(4);
    node->addNode(23);

    bstNode::printBST(node->root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (root == NULL)` is Undefined Behavior, because you reach that code before ever assigning a value to `root`.

Comment: `if (focusNode == NULL) { focusNode->right = ....` - think a moment of what that is actually doing. You *just* verified `focusNode` is NULL. And... then you dereference it. This happens several times in your code.

Comment: Unrelated, I have no idea what imbecile just voted this to close as lacking info. It has a pure reproduction and clear description (e.g. it crashes). Just letting you know it wasn't me. If anything they should have told you what I'm telling you now: run this in a debugger and it will tell you *very* quickly the prospect locations of the problems we've mentioned (and likely others).

Comment: Off-Topic:  You don't need to use the `this->` notation in your constructors.  Change the name of the parameters so they don't conflict with the member names (this should always be the case).

Comment: Change your `bstNode * root` declaration to `bstNode * root = nulptr;`.  Global variables should always be assigned a value when they are declared.

Comment: You may want to make the search tree a class instead of free standing functions;  this would take care of the global variable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews its not a global; it's a member of `bstNode` (yeah.. ouch). Still concur, but man, that's not in a good place.

Comment: We can add `while (node != NULL)` with *no* code within the loop that alters the condition potential in the recursive `print` method as a recipe for disaster as well. `if` seems a more probable course of action there.

Comment: Unrelated: you can reduce the `bstNode` constructors to a single constructor (and eliminate the default constructor as a source of uninitialized node pointers at the same time): `bstNode(int value = 0, bstNode* left = nullptr, bstNode* right = nullptr): value(value), left(left), right(right) { }` The parameters are all defaulted, so you have a default constructor that ensures you don't have gibberish right and left pointers, the value only constructor is covered by only providing the value and letting the defaults handle the rest and you have the full three parameter version if you need it.

Comment: Given that the _actual question_ here is "What exactly is a segmentation fault and how does it related to pointers?", I'm inclined to mark this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: @DrewDormann: As tempting as that is, I don't think it's really very helpful--information related more directly to the problem at hand is likely to help them a bit more.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I appreciate the feedback.  Let's wait then and see if anyone summarizes all the bugs with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate error is this

```
                if (focusNode == NULL) {

                    focusNode->left = new bstNode(value);
                }
```

this is clearly wrong, if a pointer is null you cannot use it. You have this in multiple places. Fix that and then update the question once you have got past that. How did I know this? I ran your code under my debugger and it told me immediatley, you should learn how to get the most out of your debugger.

Next

```
void addNode(int value)
```

as a method for a class defined as

```
class bstNode {

public:
    int value;
```

is very bad practice. In that method what does `value` refer to? The argument or the member variable. Get into the habit of giving member variables specific names like this

```
class bstNode {

public:
    int value_;
```

Also minor nits. The accepted style for naming classes is with leading Caps like this

```
class BstNode {

public:
    int value_;
```

or even

```
class BSTNode

class bstNode {

public:
    int value_;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the the following code...

```
while(focusNode != NULL){

    if(value > focusNode->value){

        focusNode = focusNode->right;
        if(focusNode == NULL){
            
            focusNode->right = new bstNode(value);
        }
    }
    else{

        focusNode = focusNode->left;
        if(focusNode == NULL){

            focusNode->left = new bstNode(value);
        }
    }

}
```

...you are referencing the children of a node that is **guaranteed** to be NULL because you verified that using the conditional statement. Since the node itself does not exist, it doesn't have properties like children. Imagine you're trying to communicate with the child of a person who has never existed.

The variable `focusNode` stores an address of a node. What `focusNode->value` does is that it goes to the node whose address `focusNode` stores and retrieves the value property from there.

When `focusNode` is `NULL`, it doesn't point to any node, thus you can't go there and retrieve its value property.

I wrote the code that you can replace with your while loop. I have tested it and it works:

```
while(true){
    if(value > focusNode->value){

        if(focusNode->right == NULL){
            focusNode->right = new bstNode(value);
            return;
        } else focusNode = focusNode->right;
    }
    else{

        if(focusNode->left == NULL){
            focusNode->left = new bstNode(value);
            return;
        } else focusNode = focusNode->left;
    }

}
```

I also fixed your *printBST* function. In the *printBST* function use *if* instead of *while*, because the the code inside the while loop would be executed an infinite number of times instead of printing the BST once.

```
static void printBST(bstNode* node){

    if(node != NULL){
    
        printBST(node->left);
        cout << node->value <<" ";
        printBST(node->right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;
```

I'd advise against doing this in general. It's hard to be sure what's in namespace `std`, but the short summary is "a lot, and more all the time", so making all of it visible directly can lead to problems.

```cpp
bstNode(){};
~bstNode(){};
```

These don't really accomplish anything useful. The point of a constructor is to initialize the object, but these just leave the object uninitialized, which can lead to problems--especially segmentation faults when/if you try to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

```cpp
bstNode(int value){

    this->value = value;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}
```

This is better, but I'd prefer to use a member initializer list instead of assignments inside the body of the ctor, and I'd prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`:

```cpp
bstNode(int value) 
    : value(value)
    , left(nullptr)
    , right(nullptr) {}
```

This next one:

```cpp
bstNode(int value, bstNode* left, bstNode* right){

    this->value = value;
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
}
```

...is pretty nicely written (though it could also use a member initializer list, which is usually preferable), but only rarely useful when building a binary search tree, because in normal use you only ever insert new leaf nodes, not new internal nodes.

```cpp
void addNode(int value){

    if (root == NULL){

        bstNode* node = new bstNode(value);
        root = node;
    }
    else{

        bstNode* focusNode = root;
        bstNode* parent;

        while(focusNode != NULL){

            if(value > focusNode->value){

                focusNode = focusNode->right;
                if(focusNode == NULL){
                    
                    focusNode->right = new bstNode(value);
                }
            }
            else{

                focusNode = focusNode->left;
                if(focusNode == NULL){

                    focusNode->left = new bstNode(value);
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

This is at least one obvious source of a segmentation fault--you dereference a pointer immediately after verifying that it's null.

At least for a first attempt, I think I'd use a recursive implementation, which tends to be simpler:

```cpp
void addNode(int value, bstNode *&node = root) { 
    if (node == nullptr) {
        node = new node(value);
    } else if (value < node->value) {
        addNode(value, node->left);
    } else if (value > node->value) {
        addNode(value, node->right);
    } else {
        // attempt at inserting duplicate value
    }
}
```

Note that this passes a reference to a pointer, so we can modify the "current" pointer, rather than having to track the parent pointer while traversing the tree.

```cpp
static void printBST(bstNode* node){

    while(node != NULL){
        printBST(node->left);
        cout << node->value;
        printBST(node->right);
    }    
}
```

Since we're doing this recursively, we don't need (or even want) a loop. Traversing the left sub-tree, the current node, and the right subtree traverses the entire tree, with no iteration needed.

Also note that this doesn't print any delimiter between the numbers in the nodes, so a tree containing `12, 34` and a tree containing `1, 2, 3, 4` will both be printed out as `1234`, which probably isn't very useful. Fortunately, adding a delimiter is pretty easy.

```cpp
static void printBST(bstNode* node){

    if (node != nullptr){
        printBST(node->left);
        cout << node->value << ' ';
        printBST(node->right);
    }
}
```